# Вывод товаров при нажатии на чекбокс с нужным диапазоном цены yii2

Tags: php, yii2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
есть чекбоксы

От 0-1500 
                        От 1500-3000 
                        От 3000-5000 
                        От 5000-10000 
                        От 10000-100000

Код из верстки для вывода товаров.

```
<?php if(!empty($products)): ?>
                        <?php $i = 0; foreach($products as $product) : ?>
                           <?php $mainImg = $product->getImage();?>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                                <div class="single-products">
                                    <div class="productinfo text-center">
                                         <?= Html::img($mainImg->getUrl('268x249'), ['alt' => $product->name])?>
                                        <h2>$<?php echo $product->price ?></h2>
                                        <p><a href="<?php echo \yii\helpers\Url::to(['product/view', 'id' => $product->id]) ?>"><?php echo $product->name ?></a></p>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="product-overlay">
                                        <div class="overlay-content">
                                             <?= Html::img($mainImg->getUrl('268x249'), ['alt' => $product->name])?>
                                            <h2>$<?php echo $product->price ?></h2>

                                            <p><a href="<?php echo \yii\helpers\Url::to(['product/view', 'id' => $product->id]) ?>"><?php echo $product->name ?></a></p>

                                            <a href="#" data-id="<?php echo $product->id ?>" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php if($product->new): ?>
                                        <?php echo Html::img("@web/images/home/new.png",['alt' => 'Новинка', 'class' => 'new']) ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>

                                    <?php if($product->sale): ?>
                                        <?php echo Html::img("@web/images/home/sale.png",['alt' => 'Скидки', 'class' => 'sale']) ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="choose">
                                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                                        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>Add to wishlist</a></li>
                                        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>Add to compare</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php $i++ ?>
                        <?php if($i % 3 == 0): ?>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Подскажите пожалуйста,как реализовать по клику на нужный чекбокс,вывод товаров,которые попадают под этот диапазон. есть таблица products и поле price **